# Do all Fungi have similar cells?

Tags: mycology, tissue, classification

I know that most fungi are not differentiated into tissues. And tissues are groups of specialised cells aiming to perform a collective function. Does it, then, follow that most fungi do not have distinct cells for distinct functions, and that all their cells are essentially the same? I am slightly skeptical of arriving at that conclusion; but if it is true, then I believe that it would be reasonable to say that there is no difference between the cells that give rise to spores and those who don't. How is it possible, though, for cells to be structurally similar but capable of performing varying tasks?

To summarise,

1. Do tissue-less fungi have no dissimilar cells and all are exactly the same in all respects? I believe that the answer to this question would also be applicable to other multicellular organisms as well.
2. Can it be possible for two structurally similar cells in fungi to be adept at two different tasks? This too seems to be extendable to incorporate all other multicellular organisms.

Comment: No. Only a small group.

Comment: @Marzipanherz I did not know that. My textbook didn't mention it, perhaps to be in accordance with the naive standard that I happen to be with respect to the study of Biology. I think I should edit my question to reflect what you made me to learn.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Done. I hope it's answerable now. Thanks for feedback. :)

Comment: An absence of tissue does not mean an absence of specialized cells.

Comment: @MartinKlvana I would be very grateful to you if you could add a full answer. It's been days and there's no answer still. Thanks :)

Comment: Months now......

Comment: More than 2 years now... I'm still waiting.

Comment: You are an unusually patient and (gently) persistent user!